# ubuntu - custom shell for remote servers management

Tags: shell, remote-access

One of the my main difficulties when I am administrating remote servers, its to identify the server that I'm working, once the shell is very similar between them (in fact, only the user is different in most cases).

I would like to know of is possible to create *custom* shells considering the remove server which I am connected.

Thanks for the help,
Best regards!

Answer (score 4):

If you mean *custom shell **prompt***, take a look at the PS1 variable (*man bash*, search for PS1). It has lots of options. [Here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/) is a full guide, but for a start try

```
export PS1=\u@\H \$>
```

which gives you a prompt like

```
username@full.host.name $> _
```

Comment: Instead of just the prompt, I would like to customize the entire shell window (different background, watermarks, etc.) according the remote server.

Comment: @Rui Gonçalves, well in that case you should definitively look into "screen" which is highly customizable in both look and functionalities.

Comment: byobu is pretty good too, and comes with ubuntu as standard, has colour highlighting, and gives a bar at the bottom of the screen showing hostname.

Comment: And can it be automatically configure according the remote server?

Comment: @Rui Gonçalves by default byobu (which is a set of customizations for screen) gives lots of information. If you need more to differentiate servers (like colors and such) you have to tweak the config per-server yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you leveraging the PS1 variable for customization? Not all versions of all shells handle the variable in the same manner, but most will accept a \h for hostname, \u for username,  and \w for the current working directory.

Please see [this page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) for additional options, examples, and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

regarding ps1 tweaks, this is what i use in my .bashrc

```
userName=`whoami`
if [ $userName == "root" ]
then
    PS1='\[\e[0;31m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[0;35m\]\h\[\e[0m\][$?]\[\e[0;31m\][\W]\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;31m\]\$\[\e[0m\]: '
else
    PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[0;35m\]\h\[\e[0m\][$?]\[\e[0;31m\][\W]\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;32m\]\$\[\e[0m\]: '
fi
```

It'll give the username as red when root, green otherwise. and has the hostname and return code of last command. - might help you.

Also, try byobu (as suggested in comment to mrshunz)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a unique and self-explanatory names for the hostname of your remote servers. Then, you will be able to know on which server you are working!

You can change the hostname from `/etc/hostname`. Restart the service `/etc/init.d/hostname restart`. Also, don't forget to update the `/etc/hosts` file.